# User receiving "Remote sign in" error on login but the user is signing in directly

Tags: windows-10, active-directory, group-policy, windows-server

Server 2022, Active Directory on a HyperV VM. 1 Windows 10 host as well. The VMs are on an internal Virtual net so theres no other traffic to worry about. I have created a test lab for GPO tests for my org and have noted this sign in error problem on a windows 10 client.

**Repeatable**: Every time I reboot, it will throw the error at me every time I login, for an unknown amount of time or login attempts before it allows you to log in without error.
If you got a loggedin and log out and log back in again without a reboot, theres no problem.

**Repeatable**: Also, if I reboot, log in as the local admin, log out of that, and then try logging into the domain user, it logs in no problem.

[image]

In the past, I've set up labs and users can log in wherever, no problem. But now I am looking for the group or whatever the user needs to be in to get it to stop erroring this way.

Are there any other information I can post here that would help?

[image]